# Optimisation for hadoop put with lot of small files

Tags: hadoop, put

I have to load a lot of files on my cluster (+/- 500 000) and it's take a very long time.
Each file is in gzip format and takes 80Mb of space.

For the moment I use a while loop for load my file with a put but you have maybe a best solution...

Thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can look into DataLoader of PivotalHD which loads data using map job parallel which is faster. Check this link [PivotalHD Dataloader](http://pivotalhd.cfapps.io/getting-started/data-loader.html).

Comment: Yeah your link is pretty interesting. Thanks you!

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to understand the problem the way you explain it.

HDFS supports gzip compression without splitting. As your files are ~80MB each then splitting is not a big problem for you, just make sure to use block size of 128MB of larger.

Concerning file uploading, why don't you upload the whole directory simply with -put command?

```
hadoop fs -put local/path/to/dir path/in/hdfs
```

will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, but i havn't any trouble to handle gzip file. About the put command, I can't because i have to load juste a sample of my directory and I exceed input limit when I try 'hadoop fs -put /path/*XXX.gz /path'.

Comment: find /path -name "*XXX.gz" -print0|xargs -0 -i hadoop fs -put {} /path

Answer (score 0):

You can use BuildSequenceFileFromDir of Binarypig present at https://github.com/endgameinc/binarypig